# How to use Neo4j Rest Apis for simple Match/Return Cypher

Tags: rest, neo4j, cypher

How to execute an Apoc procedure or even a  simple  match /return Cypher query using Neo4j Rest Api. I have been trying Cypher queries on Neo  for a week now and want  ability to do same  things  using Rest apis.

Answer (score 1):

The REST api has been deprecated and will not be available from the next major version of Neo4j, Neo4j 4 (due soon).
The /cypher endpoint is what you'd use if you just wanted to try it

`POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher`

```
{
  "query" : "MATCH (x {name: {startName}})-[r]-(friend) WHERE friend.name = {name} RETURN TYPE(r)",
  "params" : {
    "startName" : "I",
    "name" : "you"
  }
}
```

Docs (deprecated) available at https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current

Comment: Seems like db/data/cypher is also depreciated.. Did you mean that from next release we will only have Http api end points mentioned here https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/3.5/introduction/  (although they also dont have a match returnexample is documentation)

Comment: Yes that or the Bolt drivers. There are examples that return data (same thing whether it's via match or create), so you can explore those e.g. https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/current/actions/execute-multiple-statements/ and https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/current/actions/return-results-in-graph-format/ Please accept the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers if it helped